# Getting the name of a JButton on click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, output, actionevent

```
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == thirdBtn) {
          //System.out.println("Third Button Click");
          System.out.println(e.getSource()+" Click");
      }
  }
```

In the code above, I was wondering if instead of doing this:

```
//System.out.println("Third Button Click");
```

if I could do something like this:

```
System.out.println(e.getSource()+" Click");
```

However the code outputs:

```
BlackJack.OverBoard$BlackJackButton[,440,395,100x25,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,
    border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@7a3d8738,
    flags=16777504,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,
    defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,
    margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],
    paintBorder=false,paintFocus=true,
    pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,
    text=Change,defaultCapable=true] Click
```

I don't want this, I want to know how to get the `JButton` name and output it on click.

***EDIT:***

Some people are confused. When I say "name" (maybe that's the wrong word for it), I meant say you initialize a `JButton`

```
JButton btnExample = new JButton();
```

I want it so that when you click the button, it outputs `btnExample` in the console.

Comment: Can't be done...the way you have it now.  You have three choices.  You can either use `JButton#setText` and `JButton#getText` which is the text displayed on the screen, `JButton#setName` and `JButton#getName` which is an internal `String` reference, so it can be anything you like, or, you can create your own custom button and modify the `toString` method - which is not recommended...

Comment: *"I want it so that when you click the button, it outputs `btnExample` in the console."*  Since this information is probably not visible to the end user of a GUI and would mean nothing to them if they saw it, it seems this use-case refers to code running during development.  I suggest that what is actually needed here is a debugger, and perhaps some logging.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i understand this but it was just me wanting to know for educational purposes. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cast to a JComponent if you know that only JComponents will be the return value of `e.getSource()` I'm using `JComponent` as the cast since it gives more flexibility. If you're only using `JButtons`, you can safely cast to a `JButton` instead.

```
  @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == thirdBtn) {
                    //System.out.println("Third Button Click");
                    System.out.println(((JComponent) e.getSource()).getName()+" Click");
                }
            }
```

Feel free to replace `getName()` with `getText()`, depending on what exactly you need.

Also, the `==` operator should only be used to compare Object references, so consider casting to a JComponent from the beginning and using `.equals()` on the names or text.

**Edit**
You can't output the name of the *variable*, but you can set the name/text of the JComponent.
Eg

```
JButton btnExample = new JButton();
btnExample.setName("btnExample");
```

Or if you want "btnExample" to actually be displayed on the button:

```
JButton btnExample = new JButton();
btnExample.setText("btnExample");
```

Comment: (While I know the OP has said "name", most developers never set a components "name", instead, you might want to include an example using `getText` as well ... IMHO)

Comment: @MadProgrammer You just get auto-notified, sorry! I suspect it had to do with me forgetting the `e`, but who knows?

Comment: It would nice if down voting actually required the voter to leave a comment!

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getName() + " Click");
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what i meant :( Im asking for how to get the Name of the object. JButton btn; So when i call the comment it outputs "btn"

Comment: @Exikle Define "name".  What are expected to be printed??

Comment: +1 this is a nice dynamic approach rather than checking against the variable name.