# Determining if a JButton has been pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How can I determine if a certain JButton has been pressed in java? I have 2 buttons and depending on which button is pressed a different a value could be true or false.

```
boolean value = true;

if (event.getSource() == a)
  {
    value == true;
  }
else if (event.getSource() == b)
  { 
    value == false;
  }
```

right now no matter which button is pressed the value is false

Comment: `value == true;` is comparison, not assignment

Comment: Try printing the name of the button that you get from `event.getSource()` (after setting the name of each button if you haven't already; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14310353/423105).

Comment: Also, show us the code that populates `a` and `b`, so we can see if you have the right objects in there.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo:

```
value == true;
value == false;
```

should be:

```
value = true;
value = false;
```

"==" is testing for equality, "=" is for assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is what i have, i didnt copy / paste the code. My mistake.